# Prove or disprove that $\sum_{k=1}^p G(\lambda^k) = ps(p)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, summation

> Prove or disprove the following: if $\lambda$ is a pth root of unity not equal to one, $G(x) = (1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots (1+x^p),$ and $s(p)$ is the sum of the coefficients of $x^n$ for $n$ divisible by $p$ in $G(x)$, then $\sum_{k=1}^p G(\lambda^k) = ps(p)$.

I think the claim is true. I know how to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^p G(\lambda^k)$ (using the fact that $x^p - 1 = \prod_{k=1}^p (x-\lambda^k)$, but I'm not sure how to prove it's equal to $ps(p)$. I think I'd need to show that each sum counted by $s(p)$ gets counted p times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is true, and $G$ could be replaced by an arbitrary polynomial from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Do not think too complicated.

for every $p \nmid i$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^p \lambda^{ik} = \frac{\lambda^i(1-\lambda^{ip})}{1-\lambda^i} = 0$. For $G(x) = \sum\limits_{p \nmid i}a_ix^i + \sum\limits_{p \mid j}a_jx^j$. $\forall k={1, 2, ...p}$, $G(\lambda^k) = \sum\limits_{p \nmid i}a_i\lambda^{ik} + s(p)$. Therefore, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^pG(\lambda^k) = ps(p)$.

Your proposition is creative, it provides a fast algorithm to compute the RHS, since the LHS could be expanded using the Euler totient function.